# Api есть у любого продукта или нет?

Tags: api

Api есть у любого продукта или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос поставлен так, что явно дает понять: вы не знаете что такое *API*.
И так, [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API):

> API  — описание способов (набор классов, процедур, функций, структур или констант), которыми одна компьютерная программа может взаимодействовать с другой программой.

> API (интерфейс прикладного программирования) упрощает процесс программирования при создании приложений, абстрагируя базовую реализацию и предоставляя только объекты или действия, необходимые разработчику. Если графический интерфейс для почтового клиента может предоставить пользователю кнопку, которая выполнит все шаги для выборки и выделения новых писем, то API для ввода/вывода файлов может дать разработчику функцию, которая копирует файл из одного места в другое, не требуя от разработчика понимания операций файловой системы, происходящих за кулисами.

По надписи *упрощает процесс программирования* становится очевидно, что не у каждой программы есть API, да и он может быть скрыт от вас. Некоторые продукты (VK, Telegram и др.) могут предоставлять вам доступ к их API, другие же нет

Comment: Я учусь на тестировщика и спрашиваю с этой позиции. Т.е., если на сайте нет взаимодействия с другой системой, то и отпадает надобность в программировании api?

Comment: @ketipoint Да, **Api** не нужен

Comment: @ketipoint, внутри достаточно сложной системы фактически возникнет свой программный интерфейс (для взаимодействия между частями системы). Если в программе есть какая-то отдельная сущность (класс или модуль, например), считайте что внутри нее есть программный интерфейс. Но обычно под API подразумевают внешний интерфейс, через который например другие программы могут взаимодействовать с вашей программой.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, Api есть не у всех продуктов

Могу посоветовать книгу `RESTful Web APIs` я как раз сейчас её читаю

Api можно себе представить, как разговор между людьми, диалог

Например, вы у меня спрашиваете `Api есть у любого продукта или нет?` а я вам отвечаю `Нет, Api есть не у всех продуктов`. В этом примере вы клиент, а я сервер, от слова "сервировать" или "обслуживать". Т.е. я отвечаю на ваш вопрос или запрос. Предположим, что я - продукт, и чтобы я смог вам ответить, кто-то уже поработал ( мой папа и природа, эволюция ).

Таким образом, чтобы ваша программа ( или продукт ) могла общаться с другими программами, вы должны обучить её отвечать на запросы на том языке, на котором уже общаются другие продукты. Вы можете даже придумать свой язык, но тогда вы не поймёте, о чём вас спрашивают.

Например, у кошек тоже есть свой api - вы её гладите ( запрос ), она в ответ мурлычет ( ответ ).