# У каждого ли сайта есть веб сервис?

Tags: веб-сайт

Или веб сервис подключается по какому-то случаю?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под термином «веб сервис»?

Comment: Может стоит начинать изучение терминов не с вопросов а с чтения книг?) судя по вашим вопросам вы совершенно не понимаете тех вещей о которых пытаетесь что то узнать, и отсюда неверная постановка вопроса :)

Comment: может вы про API?

Comment: @СергейШашко про АПИ уже было https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1406355/191482  :-)

Comment: @ketipoint сразу на будущее, чтобы исключить лишние вопросы: у всех по общее только то, что те используют какой-то язык программирования........А у каждого сайта есть html, css и js (есть и без js и css , но это 0,001%, есть и без html, но это 0,000000000001%).....на этом всё))

Answer (score 0):

Итак, продолжим. Если вы ещё не читали мой ответ про api кошек, то он тут

`https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406355/api-есть-у-любого-продукта-или-нет`

Давайте начнём с того, что такое сайт. Яндекс переводчик даёт много определений https://translate.yandex.ru/?lang=en-ru&text=site но я бы объяснил слово сайт, как то место, где вы работаете. Например, ваша дача. Если к вашей даче есть дорога ( или адрес ), значит другие люди могут посещать ваш сайт ( вашу дачу )

Вы можете создать сайт и без адреса. Просто откройте Word и сохраните даже пустой документ, т.е. чистый лист, как `веб страницу` в любое место, например, на рабочий стол. У вас появится файл с раcширением `htm`. Это абсолютно чистый лист, чистая "страница". Кстати, страницу тоже можно перевести как "сайт".

Теперь мы себе представим, что ваша страница - это дача, но без дороги. Другие люди не могут к вам приехать, у вас нет сервиса дорог - способа взаимодействия или способа связи. У нас кстати в стране как раз бывают дачи без дороги (или без  веб сервиса ).

Поэтому нет, не у каждого сайта есть веб-сервис ( это способ обмена информацией, или обмена автомобилями с землёй ). Но сайт без сервиса обмена (веб) - это то же самое что и дача без дороги.

Да, вы можете работать с этим сайтом ( например, в программе Word ), в глухом лесу, где нет интернета. Но никто не сможет полюбоваться вашими результатами и сходить к вам на участок на шашлычок. (хотя - ходьба, это тоже способ взаимодействия, тогда представим, что дача в чаще - и кругом горы и деревья, не пройти и не проехать)